# Ping across VLANs using layer 2 switch

Tags: cisco, switch, layer2, packet-tracer

I'm trying to ping one PC on one particular VLAN (VLAN 80) from another PC on a different VLAN (VLAN 50). I have a layer 2 switch (Cisco 2950T), so I can't do it from within itself.

How would I be able to ping a different PC on a different VLAN through the router? Would it done through the "IP routing" command from the switch or is there another way?

Comment: You cannot do that with a layer-2 switch. Routers route between networks. If you had a layer-3 switch, you could enable routing on it. A layer-3 switch has a routing module, and you would create SVIs and address them. When you enable routing, the layer-3 switch would automatically route packets between the two different networks.

Comment: You have to use a router to do inter vlan routing. The technique is called 'router on a stick'. Or if u have L3 switch to which these PCs are directly connected then u have to create Interface VLAN corresponding to each VLAN , like Interface Vlanif 80 and Interface Vlanif50. The IP address of these Vlanif would be the default gateway of the PCs.  Switch will do routing and ping would be successful.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a router to do inter VLAN routing. The technique is called 'router on a stick'.

Or if you have a Layer 3 switch to which these PCs are directly connected then you can create an Interface VLAN corresponding to each VLAN, like `Interface Vlanif 80` and `Interface Vlanif 50`. The IP address of these Vlanif would be the default gateway of the PCs. Switch will do routing and ping would be successful.